# Voltage to current ratio in a circuit

Tags: voltage, current

How do I find the ratio
$${V_0\over I_s}$$
in the following circuit?

[image]

Comment: Voltage to current ratio is synonymous for resistance. A current source has infinite impedance, so all that is left are two resistors of known value.

Comment: We don't just do your homework for you here.

Answer (score 2):

When posting such a question it is recommended to either show what you have tried yourself or ask about what you don't understand. We are not here to calculate your homework, but help you do it yourself (and help you understand)! I will make an exception and show the calculation this one time hoping this might make you understand and be able to do the next problem yourself.

Please ask if there is something with the calculation you don't understand and I will try to explain.

**Calculation**

First we find out how much of the current flows through one of the resistors, I choose the 10 Ohm one:

$$I_Vo = I_s * \frac{20}{10 + 20}$$

now we can find \$V_0\$ by using Ohm's law:

$$V_0 = 10 * I_Vo$$

now we have both \$V_0\$ and \$I_s\$ and we can find the relationship:

$$\frac{V_0}{I_s} = \frac{10*I_Vo}{\frac{30*I_Vo}{20}} = \frac{20}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can also think of the ratio, voltage by current, to be the total resistance of your circuty. From ohms law.

[image]

or

[image]

So basicly all you have to do is calculate the resultant resistance from the parallel association.